# How to Convert Cell Datatype to String Datatype and store it in arrayList

Tags: java, jxl

I am a newbie to Java. Please guide me how to convert Cell datatype to string and store it in array List and print the same.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.LabelCell;
import jxl.NumberCell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
class ExcelReader {
    private Workbook workbook;
    private Sheet sheet;
    ArrayList<Cell> getRollNo=new ArrayList<Cell>();
    ArrayList<Cell> getName=new ArrayList<Cell>();
    ArrayList<Cell> getTotalMarks=new ArrayList<Cell>();
    public  void getExcelContents() throws BiffException, IOException
    {
        workbook= Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C://Student_Record.xls"));
        sheet=workbook.getSheet(0);
        int rowLen=sheet.getRows();
        for(int i=1;i<rowLen;i++ )
        {
            getRollNo.add((Cell)sheet.getCell(1,i));//here how to convert  cell datatype to string ,store and print same using array list object
            getName.add((Cell)sheet.getCell(2,i));
            getTotalMarks.add((Cell)sheet.getCell(3,i));
            System.out.println(getRollNo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: as `Cell` inherits from `Object`, it has the `toString()` method, so printing the list or a single cell should work out of the box. if what `toString()` creates does not suite you, you have to write a custom Cell-toString method. so what is the problem wiht your current code?

Comment: @hojui my problem is with overriding toString() method. I tried this code snippet .  public String toString()
 {
  return getRollNo.toString();
 }

Answer (score 0):

getContents() method form the jxl.Cell class should do your job. It returns the contents of a cell as a string.

Reference : http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Cell.html

If you want to store the string, you will need to change your array list to String type instead of Cell

```
ArrayList<String> getRollNo=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then add the data in your loop like this

```
getRollNo.add((Cell)sheet.getCell(1,i)).getContents();
```

Else keep your ArrayList of Cell type only and when you want to display the content call the getContents() method on each cell object

```
ArrayList<Cell> getRollNo=new ArrayList<Cell>();

getRollNo.add((Cell)sheet.getCell(1,i));

for(Cell c : getRollNo)
{
     System.out.println(c.getContents());
}
```